# How will records in Clojure 1.3 change?

Tags: clojure

I have tried to use records in Clojure 1.2 but they seem very messy and incomplete. I was considering waiting until their API has envolved and stabilised before I use them. Does anyone know what changes are due for 1.3, or are they pretty much fixed as they are now?

### Update:

As shown from the link in the answer there could still be alot of changes to records and their related features, so it is not a good idea to use records unless you are prepared to rework the code which uses records in the future

### Update 2:

And just to clarify: I guess I meant that alot of the upcoming features in records are being added by "Enhanced Clojure records" and other such libraries, when really it may be better to wait for these features to be in the core as once these features are in the core of clojure then the code will end up being rewritten to use the clojure core version of records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/defrecord+improvements

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is very clear after reading it that Clojure records are far from stable as far as the API is concerned, so I think the advice is to wait until they have matured. Thanks :)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by stability. There are currently no plans to change existing API -- the changes are entirely additive.

Comment: @stuart Yes, I meant the API. I guess I meant that alot of the upcoming features in records are being added by "Enhanced Clojure records" and other such libraries, when really it may be better to wait for these features to be in the core